# How to remove checkbox from div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to remove `checkbox` from `div` using jQuery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) in combination with a selector, like this:

```
$("#myDiv :checkbox").remove();
```

Which selector you'd use depends on your markup, you can read more on selectors [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Find_me:_Using_selectors_and_events) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: @sam - In that case you can do `$("#checkboxid").remove()` directly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use animation, like fadeOut.  It turns your page being more pleasent

```
$("#myDiv :checkbox").fadeOut('slow');
```

**API Documentation**

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/